# How to use Euclidean Color Filtering in c# ? I have error in => filter.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(215, 30, 30);

Tags: c#

The image processing filter filters pixels, which color is inside/outside of RGB         sphere with specified center and radius - it keeps pixels with colors inside/outside of the specified sphere and fills the rest with specified color.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Bitmap img, img2;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Clearing previously selected image from picture box
            pictureBox1.Image = null;

            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Images";

            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Images|*.jpg; *.bmp; *.png";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString() != "")
            {
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
            }
            img = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Browse the image...");
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // create filter
        EuclideanColorFiltering filter = new EuclideanColorFiltering();
        // set center colol and radius
        filter.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(215, 30, 30);
        filter.Radius = 100;
        // apply the filter
        filter.ApplyInPlace(img);


        pictureBox2.Image = img;
    }
}
```

}

```
// I have got error in "filter.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(215, 30, 30);"  this line

please help me..
```

Comment: Error is that "Can not convert from System.Drawing.Color to AForg.Imaging.RGB" in line filter.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(215, 30, 30);

Comment: When you are in Rome, act like a Roman.  Use filter.CenterColor = new AForge.Imaging.RGB(215, 30, 30);

Comment: Brother Why I get error on 'IntRange' in this code :  ColorFiltering filter = new ColorFiltering();
    filter.Red = new IntRange(100, 255);

Comment: Where is this part of the code ? I can't find it...

Comment: Another example. In the same code I am using ColorFiltering instead of EuclideanColorFiltering

Answer (score 0):

An **ARGB** color is defined by 4 canals: alpha (the opacity), red, green and blue.

So you may use **Color.FromRgb** if it exist, or **Color.FromArgb** with 255 for the first parameter (alpha).

Comment: Brother it is still giving the error  "Defination of 'FromRgb' not defined"

Comment: Try filter.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 215, 30, 30);

Comment: Brother Why I get error on 'IntRange' in this code :  ColorFiltering filter = new ColorFiltering();
    filter.Red = new IntRange(100, 255);

Answer (score 0):

You must notice, it is Aforge library filter. This is not using an Color from System.Drawing.Color but this using RGB() from Aforge libraries. You can simply fix this error using new RGB(Color).
Like in example:

```
filter.CenterColor = new RGB(Color.FromArgb(215, 30, 30));
```

You have definition of RGB() in AForge.Imaging class.

And if You want to change an radius using property like int, you must remember, `filter.Radius` allow to use only `short` (not int) from value 0 to 450. Then only use `Convert.ToInt16` on int and it's done.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// create filter
EuclideanColorFiltering filter = new EuclideanColorFiltering( );
// set center colol and radius
filter.CenterColor = new RGB( 215, 30, 30 );
filter.Radius = 100;
// apply the filter
filter.ApplyInPlace( image );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap d =new Bitmap(ofile.FileName);
for (int i = 0; i < d.Width; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < d.Height; j++)
{
                    Color C1 = d.GetPixel(i, j);
                    int r2 = C1.R;
                    int g2 = C1.G;
                    int b2 = C1.B;
                    int red = (byte)(.238 * r2 + .16 * g2 + .16 * b2);
                    r2 = red;
                    g2 = red;
                    b2 = red;
                    d.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(r2, g2, b2));

                }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Instead of just posting a chunk of code, can you also explain what it does?